# why we declare variable as a reference in private section of a class

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers

I know how useful it is to  declare variable as a reference or pointer in a function, but I just wonder why we declare it as a *reference* in the private section of a class.

example

```
class DoSomething
{
  private : int& t_; // why not just 'int t;'
};
```

How about if we declare the variable without reference, and define the object of a class as a pointer or reference? Is this not good practice?

Comment: You can declare them as `public` or `protected` as well. It depends on the context and the programmer's needs. However, you have to initialize them in the constructor's initialization list.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what public, protected and private mean. Look up `encapsulation` for example. It's a concept orthogonal to pointer/reference (or any kind of type for that matter).

Comment: Its not about private or  public . I only wants to know why  it is useful in declaring variable as reference in class . What I  think is even though if one gives a variable without reference still that variable is associated with an object so whteher we give reference or without reference does it make any difference and when object is destroyed all its variable will be destroyed so I dont know why people give a reference?. I asked this question to know condition where reference is useful ? ist not  about " big deal or something "

Comment: Just a simple request , when people down vote the question , could they please care to tell why have they down voted the question so that in future we will know better.

Comment: It's useful when you want to have a reference to an int, and not an int, as the data member. What if I asked you - why `int t;`? Why not `std::string t;`?

Comment: @Praetorian, Thanks for reply , exactly the same thing is bugging me ,in what situation do we need reference for a variable,  generally we change  value of a variable via function . so if function changes the value of a variable why we need ref?

Comment: Question is **Primarily Opinion-Based** and **Too Broad**.

Comment: @samprat _'Just a simple request ...'_ See Jason's comment. At least this was my reason to down and close vote ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Thanks mate. but still just for clarity I am asking , if some one has conceptual problem then how can he /she will ask the questions if people will down vote it immediately? I mean when u guys said its broad but in my view I have only issue with ref in declaration now tell me how would I narrow down by question or make it less broad?

Comment: @samprat Yes, your question is too broad. It totally depends on the actual use case, if it's a good idea to use a reference, a copy, smart pointer, or may be even something like a hash key, as member to access a reference for your desired value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare the variable as `int`, its value would be "divorced" from the variable from which it has been initialized. If you keep it a reference, the variable would be "tracking" the variable with which it has been initialized:

```
class demoRef {
    int &r;
public:
    demoRef(int& x) : r(x) {}
    void show() {cout << r << endl;}
};
class demoCopy {
    int r;
public:
    demoCopy(int& x) : r(x) {}
    void show() {cout << r << endl;}
};

int main() {
    int x = 123;
    demoRef dRef(x);
    demoCopy dCopy(x);
    dRef.show();
    dCopy.show();
    x = 456;
    dRef.show();
    dCopy.show();
    return 0;
}
```

This code produces the output below:

```
123
123
456
123
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/obN2k7)

Note: this is only an illustration of what you *can* do with a reference to an `int`. It is not meant to imply that you *should* do something like this without being extra careful, because a hidden reference like this makes your code harder to read.

Comment: Thanks A lot , it helped me to clear my concept.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons you might have a reference member. An example from the standard library is the [`back_insert_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator), which keeps a reference (or a pointer) to a container in order to call that container's `push_back` function.

Note that with any class like this, which stores a reference or pointer to another object, you need to take the same care as you would with a raw reference or pointer.  That is, you need to be wary of dangling references, and ensure that you don't use the reference past the lifetime of the referent.

Comment: Thanks mate..  with others including u it help me to get better understanding of class decl

Answer (score 0):

When you store a reference to a variable in a class, the outcome of changing the variable is:

1. You can change the variable in a member function of `DoSomething` and have that change be visible outside the class.
2. You can change the variable outside `DoSomething` and have that change be visible inside `DoSomething`.

The key question is: Where is it useful?

1. I have often found it useful in a functor that is passed to some of the functions in the standard library.

   @BenjaminLindley already gave you a very good example of that.
2. I have often found it useful in Factory Patterns when a concrete Product is created using the data stored in a concrete Factory but the data is too expensive to copy.
3. I have used it in classes that implement a functional interface. These classes hold references to other data when:

   3.1. The class needs to access to the data but it is too expensive to copy the data.

   3.2. It makes no sense to copy the data or copying is prohibited by design (such as `std::ofstream`).

   3.3. The class needs to update the data and make it visible to the calling code.

Comment: @Sahu,Thanks a lot. def very helpful post